# Speed Of Data Entering in database

Tags: c#, .net, database, sql-server-2005, oledb

I am developing one windows applicatiopn , in which i am uploading one textfile.
In that text file there are 5000 rows in which comma[,] separated data is there.
I am using oledb connections[MS Access] in backend.
I am fetching the comma separated data from file and inserting it in database.

But as i am observing is that data is nearly about 15000-16000 records.
It is taking nearly about 7 records per seconds in inserting.

I want to increase this speed.

Do that depend upon what we use at backend as a database?

Can sql server 2005 increase the speed instead of MS Access?

Please help me for this.

Please See The Code:

```
string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
StreamReader inputData = new StreamReader(file);
while ((line = inputData.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    subLine = line.Split(',');

    /*Taking Unique ID from tradefile table*/
    int ID=0;
    try
    {
        da=new OleDbDataAdapter("select max(ID) from tradeFile",con);
        DataSet ds=new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() == "")
            {
            }
            else
            {
                ID = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
                ID++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }


    try
    {
        string unknown="unknown Fileld";
        con.Open();
       // int j=subLine.Length;
        //for(int i=0;i<subLine.Length;i++)
        {
            int i = 0;
           //int j=subLine.Length;
           //int index=subLine.Length-j;
           cmd=new OleDbCommand(
               "insert into tradeFile values('"+ID+"','"+
               subLine[i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+subLine[++i].ToString()+"','"+
               unknown+"')",con);
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
    //counter++;
}
```

Comment: Are you inserting using ADO.NET? Or do you use O/R mapping of some sort?

Comment: Then you should use batching, or even better, `SQLBulkCopy`. I've added an answer below.

Comment: You're creating an OleDbDataAdapter, opening your connection, creating a command object and then closing the connection for every line you write: using one of each for the whole process would speed it up.

Comment: Oh. thank You @stuartd I will definitely implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can increase speed by insertint multiple rows at once. As far as i know sql-server allows to insert 1000 rows in one query, wich is 5-6 queries to DB instead of 5-6k queries. Not sure how many rows can handle ms access. Also, insert speed depends on RDBMS of course

**upd:**

Wierd that you do additional query to get new id for the table. You really should use autoincrement field, that's a first.
Second: your result insert query should look like this:

```
insert into tradeFile (field1, field2 ... fieldN) 
values (f1value1, f2value1...fNvalue1), (f1value2, f2value2...fNvalu2) etc.
```

And third - you need to keep in mind that you can't insert more than N (for example 1000 in SQL Server) values at once, so your code might be sort of following:

```
string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
StreamReader inputData = new StreamReader(file);
int values = 0;
const int maxValuesPerInsert = 1000;
string insertQuery = string.empty;
while ((line = inputData.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    subLine = line.Split(',');
    /*do some work to extract values (lemme call em value1, value2...)*/
    if (values < maxValuesPerInsert - 1)
    {
        insertQuery += string.format("({0}, {1}, {2}),", value1, value2, value3);
        values++;
    }
    else
    {
        insertQuery += string.format("({0}, {1}, {2})", value1, value2, value3); //just to get rid of last comma            
        var query = string.format("insert into tradeFile (field1, field2, field 3) values {0}", insertQuery);
        /*do your db query*/
        insertQuery = string.empty;
        values = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: sir, about adding multiple rows at a time>>>please look at my code in edited question. I have put insert query in while loop so as to fetch the record and insert it accordingly.

Comment: Updated my answer, wrote code in notepad, so there might be some errors :) but whole algorythm is close to be working

Comment: Creating the INSERT string by concatenating strings is considered bad practice, making the app prone to SQL injection attacks (in this case the data is being loaded from a file but just to emphasize that this is not a common way to do it). Also, if you already used `Split` to get a bunch of strings, then a `StringBuilder` might be a better choice to simply append all values. And, it's worth mentioning that inserting multiple rows with one statement ("row construction") is available only with SQL Server 2008 and newer.

Comment: Well, i'm not telling that this would be perfect production code, this is just explanation of how would be better to do without unnessesary details

Comment: >>Wierd that you do additional query to get new id for the table. You really should use autoincrement field, that's a first  >> Sir, in MS Access autoincreament is not working as it works in SQLServer 2008/2005 @Sergio

Comment: haven't use ms access for a long long while :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SQL server is a lot faster and reliable than MSACCESS.

Avoid using access for big databases (a few thousands records could be big for access), when you use contemporary access with more than one connection or when you have intensive workload.

SQL Server express could be enough (and it's free, see limitations here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldensetup/thread/0e781eb4-1c27-4777-9bd8-bc9e1ae3e803/ )

Antoher "workaround" could be using multiple insert in one query or using a BULK insert (that I'm not sure is supported in access)

Comment: sir, about adding multiple rows at a time>>>please look at my code in edited question. I have put insert query in while loop so as to fetch the record and insert it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Off course, MsSQL server using instead of MS Access will increase the speed.
Also as I think you are making for each row 1 query. You have to add few rows in each query. This will increase the speed.

What algorith you use to split the data in text file?

Comment: sir please go through my edited question, I have put code within it

Comment: In that i am putting insert query in  while loop [ So as to read data and insert it accordingly]

Answer (score 0):

> I want to increase this speed.

You should look up [**ADO.NET batching**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aadf8fk2.aspx).

Basically, you create a DataAdapter (i.e. an [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879f39d8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you opt for SQL Server), where you specify your update, insert and delete commands, and then set the [`DataAdapter.UpdateBatchSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.updatebatchsize%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property to a value larger than 1 (e.g. try 1000 and see what happens).

With modest hardware, you should be able to insert **~10,000 rows per second**, but I would try a couple of different batch sizes and **profile**.

> Can sql server 2005 increase the speed instead of MS Access?

Yes, you should consider switching to SQL Server if you need to work with larger sets of data. No need to use the 2005 edition, though; [SQL Server 2012 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) is the free edition of choice as of 2012.

If you really have huge numbers of rows (e.g. 100,000 rows) to insert at once, you can also consider using [`SQLBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). `SQLBulkCopy` is especially suitable for scenarios where you copy data between different tables on the same server.